# Vector animation in API 25

Tags: android, animation, vector

I have Vector drawable animation. It works properly in API 17-24, but has issues in API 25. Animation runs, but vectors move in different order.

Here is my vector drawable

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:drawable="@drawable/logo_vector_white">
    <target
        android:name="eye"
        android:animation="@animator/blink_eye" />
</animated-vector>
```

Here is the animation

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="300"
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:valueTo="0.05"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="300"
        android:propertyName="translateX"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:valueTo="155"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
</set>
```

Here is how i run it

```
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Drawable animation = logo.getDrawable();
                if (animation instanceof Animatable) {
                    ((Animatable) animation).start();
                }
            }
        }, 300);
```

I found, that starting from API 25, AnimatedVectorDrawable [runs on RenderThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html). If this causes the issue, how to resolve it? I also tried to bundle all animation files to single xml, but got the same result.

Comment: What order do the animations run in on different versions?

Comment: @LewisMcGeary please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to do only horizontal scale animation of my vector object (it's blinking eye, that scales by X to 0 and then returns to the previous state). I didn't knew about pivots and used one more translateX animation to compensate horizontal movement of vector. This workaround was working until API 25, when it started to execute on RenderThread.

Fixed this by adding android:pivotX to the group and removing objectAnimator with translateX property. Also added android:valueFrom="1" (without it on API 25 animation was switching to valueTo instantly).

Here is the full xml.

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                 tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:width="292dp"
                android:height="108dp"
                android:viewportHeight="108.0"
                android:viewportWidth="292.0">
            <path
                android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:pathData="M7,12L93,12A7,7 0,0 1,100 19L100,34A7,7 0,0 1,93 41L7,41A7,7 0,0 1,0 34L0,19A7,7 0,0 1,7 12z"
                android:strokeColor="#00000000"
                android:strokeWidth="1"/>

            <group
                android:name="eye"
                android:pivotX="160">
                <path
                    android:name="right_eye"
                    android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:pathData="M161.5,26.5m-16.5,0a16.5,16.5 0,1 1,33 0a16.5,16.5 0,1 1,-33 0"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"
                    android:strokeWidth="1"/>
            </group>

            <path
                android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:pathData="M7,67L93,67A7,7 0,0 1,100 74L100,89A7,7 0,0 1,93 96L7,96A7,7 0,0 1,0 89L0,74A7,7 0,0 1,7 67z"
                android:strokeColor="#00000000"
                android:strokeWidth="1"/>
            <path
                android:name="left_eye"
                android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:pathData="M161.5,81.5m-16.5,0a16.5,16.5 0,1 1,33 0a16.5,16.5 1,1 1,-33 0"
                android:strokeColor="#00000000"
                android:strokeWidth="1"/>
            <path
                android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:pathData="M241.46,1.54L289.96,50.04A5,5 119.52,0 1,289.96 57.11L278.07,69A5,5 0,0 1,271 69L222.5,20.5A5,5 57.75,0 1,222.5 13.43L234.39,1.54A5,5 86.11,0 1,241.46 1.54z"
                android:strokeColor="#00000000"
                android:strokeWidth="1"/>
            <path
                android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:pathData="M241.5,106L290,57.5A5,5 60.48,0 0,290 50.43L278.11,38.54A5,5 0,0 0,271.04 38.54L222.54,87.04A5,5 112.86,0 0,222.54 94.11L234.43,106A5,5 0,0 0,241.5 106z"
                android:strokeColor="#00000000"
                android:strokeWidth="1"/>
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>

    <target android:name="eye">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="300"
                    android:propertyName="scaleX"
                    android:repeatCount="1"
                    android:repeatMode="reverse"
                    android:valueFrom="1"
                    android:valueTo="0"
                    android:valueType="floatType"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>

</animated-vector>
```